# Mobile Optimized Facebook Comment Box?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to have the Facebook Comments plugin and it's elements embedded wrap and be responsive? Following the setup below on Facebook's example:

**Javascript SDK**

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=id_example";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**Rendering DIV** (Using their data-mobile attribute to show the mobile-optimized version or not.)

```
<div class="fb-comments data-mobile="true"></div>
```

Generates the following, but nothing wraps so the users won't be able to access the post/submit button. Also other peoples comments that are long won't wrap causing text to get cut off.

[image]

Can this only be done by using the Graph API and building a custom commenting box/module that handles my sites facebook comments for pages?

Comment: The comments plugin has a property called data-mobile that should be automatically detected when somebody uses mobile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#settings Is that not working for you? Can you provide a link?